# angular.js: using a directive to insert another directive as an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

For example, [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has a directive called 'typeahead' that suggests values for a field. Let's say I want to make a directive that I can use as an attribute for an element that will cause colours to be suggested for that element.

Here's an attempt that fails...

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('suggestcolors', function () {
    return {
      compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
        attrs.$set("typeahead", "color for color in ['red', 'blue', 'green']");
      }
    };
  });
```

View:

```
<textarea ng-model="foo" suggestcolors></textarea>
```

When I inspect the textarea, the attribute has been set, but it doesn't do anything. The same thing happens if I move the change to attrs to the link function. Setting the typeahead attribute directly in the view works as expected:

```
<textarea ng-model="foo" typeahead="color for color in ['red', 'blue', 'green']"></textarea>
```

(But I want to be able to insert this attribute dynamically, for reasons of DRY. My actual use case is more complicated than this.)

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104192/bind-ng-click-function-in-compile-with-angularjs) (about dynamically adding ng-click behaviour in the compile step), but never directly answered.

Answer (score 6):

After the compilation, AngularJS only calls `$compile` for all of the child elements. The element itself is not automatically recompiled, so adding a directive at this stage will not have effect. In your case, I think you can change it from a compile function to a link function (so you get a `scope` argument), and call `$compile(element)(scope)` yourself.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4D2s/1/) where I have a directive that adds `style="color: red"`, and another directive that "dynamically" adds that directive. It doesn't work, unless I call `$compile` afterwards.

HTH!

Comment: If you take a look at the console in that Fiddle, you'll see that an infinite recursion happens (`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`). Also, calling `$compile` like this is a way for watchers to leak as you don't unregister the watchers called by the previous call to `$compile`.

Comment: An example of leaking watchers: http://plnkr.co/edit/3Y1BoNuNO2HFA98JS7oR?p=preview

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't spot that! I meant to unset the attribute after compiling, but your point of leaking watches makes sense. If you have a complete answer to the question, I'll upvote your answer. Thanks!

Comment: As for the question in the title, no, I don't have any really good answer to it.